# error upon heroku create, rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, typeerror

I'm running rails 2.3.8 on Windows XP and trying for my first time to deploy on Heroku. Everything works fine in development but when I do `heroku create`, I get the following, any ideas? Thanks.

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:50: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:130:in `extract_description': wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc) (TypeError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:126:in `extract_summary'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:64:in `method_added'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb:14
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:17:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:16:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:16:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.1.4/bin/heroku:13
        from C:/Ruby/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby/bin/heroku:19
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more information. i.e. What as the exact command you ran. Did you try heroku create appname?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I tried heroku create appname as well as heroku create, both withotu success. I tried lower versions as well and they did not work. Someone else entered this ticket on the heroku github #113 but has not been resolved. I suspect its a gem incompatibility but I don't know how to "line the stars up"

Comment: I guess it was a bug in the version at hte time (2.1.4). The current version (2.2.1) resolves this issue